# How to obtain hover effect on image similar to below mentioned

Tags: html, css

I have code written here https://codepen.io/smarty_tech/pen/dXEjXbb Which I want to be like the site  http://mahno.com.ua/en/architecture .
Trying to achieve this but what all i can do is stated above. Code is totally in CSS and HTML.

```
    <div>  
        <div>
            <h1 class="title">Architecture</h1>
        </div>
    <!--section-title end-->

        <div>
            <div>
                <span class="tim">Kube house</span>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">  
                </a>
                <span class="tim">Kube house</span>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="tim">Kube house</span>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                    </a>
                    <span class="tim">Kube house</span>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="tim">Kube house</span>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                    </a>
                    <span class="tim">Kube house</span>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                    </a>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="tim">Kube house</span>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                    </a>
                    <span class="tim">Kube house</span>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">  
                    </a>
                    <span class="tim">Kube house</span>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="tim">Kube house</span>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                    </a>
                    <span class="tim">Kube house</span>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                    </a>
                    <span class="tim">Kube house</span>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                    </a>
                </div>
            <div>    
        </div>

    </div>        <!--product-list end-->
</div>
```

EDIT : I checked the site via inspect element and find the four div's which have been used for the animation but the problem is that if I'm using div then all the images are aligned vertically but i want them in pairs of 2 and 3.I have tried many ways out but the proper effect cannot be accomplished.

Comment: Just inspect the site, you can see the lines are just 4 divs being animated in width/height.

Comment: @Paulie_D i have put quite a great effort in searching as well as implementing the code . The techniques you are mentioning have also used that however my image is not being loaded in <i style="background-image:url()"></i>  here thats why i used <img> tag

Comment: I fail to see how that is relevant,